# How can I parse the text from these results into parameters for a separate script?

Tags: windows-10, powershell, script, shell-script

I need to extract `client_TargetText` and `AnotherTargetText_110953_140521` from the results I get when running the `whoami /groups` command:

Powershell Results:

```
Group Name                                 Type             SID                                           Attributes
========================================== ================ ============================================= ==================================================
Everyone                                   Well-known group S-1-1-0                                       Mandatory group, Enabled by default, Enabled group
BUILTIN\Users                              Alias            S-1-5-32-545                                  Mandatory group, Enabled by default, Enabled group
NT AUTHORITY\INTERACTIVE                   Well-known group S-1-5-4                                       Mandatory group, Enabled by default, Enabled group
CONSOLE LOGON                              Well-known group S-1-2-1                                       Mandatory group, Enabled by default, Enabled group
NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users           Well-known group S-1-5-11                                      Mandatory group, Enabled by default, Enabled group
NT AUTHORITY\This Organization             Well-known group S-1-5-15                                      Mandatory group, Enabled by default, Enabled group
LOCAL                                      Well-known group S-1-2-0                                       Mandatory group, Enabled by default, Enabled group
MYDOMAIN\GGM-FIRE-PC                       Group            S-1-5-21-457414007-2867176591-488352320-6061  Mandatory group, Enabled by default, Enabled group
MYDOMAIN\myles_gp                          Group            S-1-5-21-457414007-2867176591-488352320-12531 Mandatory group, Enabled by default, Enabled group
MYDOMAIN\GGM-RDP                           Group            S-1-5-21-457414007-2867176591-488352320-13873 Mandatory group, Enabled by default, Enabled group
MYDOMAIN\client_TargetText                 Group            S-1-5-21-457414007-2867176591-488352320-7924  Mandatory group, Enabled by default, Enabled group
MYDOMAIN\AnotherTargetText_110953_140521   Group            S-1-5-21-457414007-2867176591-488352320-13947 Mandatory group, Enabled by default, Enabled group
Authentication authority asserted identity Well-known group S-1-18-1                                      Mandatory group, Enabled by default, Enabled group
Mandatory Label\Medium Mandatory Level     Label            S-1-16-8192
PS C:\Users\test.dev>
```

How would I go about grabbing `client_TargetText` and removing the `client_` so it becomes just `TargetText` and then make this `$Param1` in the script below?
(`client_` is always present in the text I need to grab for $Param1)

Then how would I go about grabbing `AnotherTargetText_110953_140521` so it can be made into `$Param2` in the script below?
(The desired text for `$Param2` is always suffixed by `6digits_6digits` in these AD groups)

My goal is to somehow send this text over into a script I use for creating server shortcuts on user desktops.

The results will be different for each user when `whoami` runs so I think the only wildcards that can be used are `client_` and `6digits_6digits`. Any helping me towards finding this answer very much appreciated as I am trying to learn how this would work but can't figure it out.

The script below is the desired outcome after successfully parsing those two pieces of text over and turning them into `$Param1` and `$Param2`:

```
function set-shortcut {
param ( [string]$SourceLnk, [string]$DestinationPath )
    $WshShell = New-Object -comObject WScript.Shell
    $Shortcut = $WshShell.CreateShortcut($SourceLnk)
    $Shortcut.TargetPath = $DestinationPath
    $Shortcut.Save()
    }

    try{

$Param1 = TargetText
$Param2 = AnotherTargetText_110953_140521
$SourcePath = \\server\data\designs\$Param1\$Param2\data_store"

set-shortcut "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\data_store.lnk" "$SourcePath"

     "This worked"
     
pause
}

catch
   {
    
    "This didn't work"
}
pause
```

Comment: take a look at the `Get-LocalUser` cmdlet. it lists the groups the account is a member of. then you can filter for your pattern in the `.Name` property. once you have the group name as text, just do a `-replace` OR a `.Split()` as you prefer.

Comment: Thank you Lee I completely forgot about Get-LocalUser I will see into that

Comment: you are most welcome! glad to have helped a little bit ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is being ran with PowerShell:

1. Let's use the proper opening, and closing quotes (`""`).
2. Let's also use the proper environment variables: `$env:USERPROFILE`.

I really couldn't make too much sense in what you were trying to accomplish, so I did what I think you meant. As far as your parameters for your function, that i'm still lost on.

```
function Set-ShortCut {
    Param ( 
        [string]$SourceLnk, 
        [string]$DestinationPath 
    )
        
        $WshShell = New-Object -comObject WScript.Shell
        $Shortcut = $WshShell.CreateShortcut($SourceLnk)
        $Shortcut.TargetPath = $DestinationPath
        $Shortcut.Save()

}


$Groups = Whoami /Groups /FO CSV | ConvertFrom-Csv

$Param1, $Param2 = $Groups.'Group Name'.Where{
    
        $_ -match 'client_' -or `
        $_ -match '(_\d{6}){2}'

    } -replace 'client_|MYDOMAIN\\'



$SourcePath = "\\server\data\designs\$Param1\$Param2\data_store"

Set-ShortCut -SourceLnk "$env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\data_store.lnk" -DestinationPath $SourcePath
```

Luckily, `whoami` has a `/FO CSV` option which we can use to convert it to a proper PowerShell object using `ConvertFrom-Csv`. After the object conversion, we can use some *Regex* matching to get what you're after assuming that's exactly how the names are displayed. Please note the double assignment of `$Param1`, and `$Param2` as it splits the results into those two variables. Also, in trying to avoid the *pipeline*, I used the `.Where()\{}` **operator** (*yes, it's considered an operator*) for faster parsing.

*I would suggest in looking into the the cmdlet mentioned by @Lee_Daily, to include the method he provide in getting the results you're after.*

**EDIT:**
You can try separating the filtering into two variables for explicit filtering. Although not the best solution, it should work:

```
function Set-ShortCut {
    Param ( 
        [string]$SourceLnk, 
        [string]$DestinationPath 
    )
        
        $WshShell = New-Object -comObject WScript.Shell
        $Shortcut = $WshShell.CreateShortcut($SourceLnk)
        $Shortcut.TargetPath = $DestinationPath
        $Shortcut.Save()

}

$Groups = WhoAmI /Groups /FO CSV | ConvertFrom-Csv

$Param1 = $Groups.'Group Name'.Where{ $_ -match 'client_' } -replace 'client_|MYDOMAIN\\'
$Param2 = $Groups.'Group Name'.Where{ $_ -match '(_\d{6}){2}' } -replace 'MYDOMAIN\\'

$SourcePath = "\\server\data\designs\$Param1\$Param2\data_store"

Set-ShortCut -SourceLnk "$env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\data_store.lnk" -DestinationPath $SourcePath
```

Comment: Thank you Abraham for the lesson there. The script now works as intended. Thanks.

Comment: Awesome man, glad it worked first try.

Comment: Hi Abraham, sorry I've now done several tests with different users and noticed that in some circumstances that the target text for $Param1 and $Param2 get switched around. So when the script creates a shortcut to the server path the shortcut doesn't work. Is there a way to explicitly tell the script to assign $Param1 to the text containing 'client_' and $Param2 to be assigned the text containing _6digits?

Comment: @Mastaxx, see my edit.

Comment: That's done it. My version of attempting that was way off! Thanks alot for that!

Comment: Glad to hear bro!

Comment: @AbrahamZinala - you can leave off the  backtick after the `-or` since PoSh knows the operator is followed by "more stuff". [*grin*]

Comment: @Lee_Daily, I'm tracking lol just figured I show my intent. Thank ya kind sir:)